# How to process AWS CDK CfnSecurityGroup in Java

Tags: java, aws-cdk

The following code generates a "software.amazon.jsii.JsiiObject cannot be cast to software.amazon.awscdk.services.ec2.CfnSecurityGroupIngress"  error on the line of code "CfnSecurityGroupIngress sgi = (CfnSecurityGroupIngress)obj;"

```
    CfnSecurityGroup cfnSecurityGroup = (CfnSecurityGroup) resource_SecurityGroup.getCfnresource();

    if (cfnSecurityGroup.getSecurityGroupIngress() != null) {

      
      List<CfnSecurityGroupIngress> cfnSecurityGroupIngress = (List<CfnSecurityGroupIngress>) cfnSecurityGroup.getSecurityGroupIngress();
      
      
      ListIterator<CfnSecurityGroupIngress> it = cfnSecurityGroupIngress.listIterator();
      while (it.hasNext()) {
        Object obj = it.next();
        LOG.debug("obj: " + obj.toString());
        CfnSecurityGroupIngress sgi = (CfnSecurityGroupIngress)obj;
        LOG.debug("getFromPort" + sgi.getFromPort());
      }
```

How do you get access to the SecurityGroupIngress properties?

Note that I've since determined that CfnSecurityGroup.IngressProperty is an interface type that is present in the cfnSecurityGroupIngress.listIterator(). I'm not sure what to do with it however.

Maven

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>software.amazon.awscdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdk-cloudformation-include</artifactId>
        <version>1.79.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Regards
Conteh

Comment: What to you get if you output the class of obj?

Comment: @chris class software.amazon.jsii.JsiiObject. Any idea how to determine the AWS type of a class software.amazon.jsii.JsiiObject?

Comment: Presumably JsiiObject. Apologies I'm just speculating here about stuff I don't know, but seems like the answer is in source of the class that is returned by that iterator. Maybe worth a quick decompile if Javadoc doesn't give you the answer. I'm assuming it's not open source

Comment: @Chris I suppose it all starts with the problem that  cfnSecurityGroup.getSecurityGroupEgress() is returning an Object and I don't know what type that Object is. Although it seems to cast to (List<CfnSecurityGroupIngress>)

Comment: Yep, I'm well out my depth as I've never touched this stuff. Best guess is that JsiiObject is some kind of wrapper that you'd have to interrogate to figure out how to get what you want from it

Comment: Sorry - hope someone comes back with a helpful answer, or you can find something useful - it's hard to find much on the internet, I'm so used to open source I'd forgotten how difficult it can be to work with this kind of stuff. Can you get hold of the Javadoc for that artefact via maven?

Comment: No problem,thanks for the effort, yeah the javadoc suggest the type returned by getSecurityGroupEgress is Object. This may be the root of the problem

Comment: Ha ha, bad Javadoc is the root of many problems. It's taught me to write proper documentation that will help people that have to pick up my code, or make use of libraries I've written. A return type of Object without any explanation of what actual type you might expect at runtime, and why, seems pretty inadequate, but I've worked with enough third party code to not be surprised.

Answer (score 0):

I note that one way to access the parameters is to resolve

```
        LOG.debug(this.resolve(obj).toString());
```

which returns the json string

```
{cidrIp={Ref=SSHLocation}, fromPort=22, ipProtocol=tcp, toPort={Ref=ToPort}}
```